# JQuery Validate multiple Forms with invisible Google Captcha

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, recaptcha

I use JQuery Validate with Google Captcha V2. Depending on the page there may be several forms. The first form works without problems. With the others I always get a "**missing-input-response**". But I do not find the error

```
var _form;
$('.modal__validator').each(function () {
        $(this).validate(
            {
                // ...
                submitHandler: function (form) {
                    if (typeof grecaptcha !== 'undefined') {
                        _form = form;
                        grecaptcha.execute();
                    } else {
                        console.error('Recaptcha could not be inited');
                    }
                }
            }
        );
    });
```

This Function get fired using callback

```
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCaptcha&render=explicit
```

```
function onloadCaptcha() {
    var recaptchas = document.querySelectorAll('div[class=g-recaptcha]'),
        recaptchaObj = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < recaptchas.length; i++) {
       recaptchaObj[i] = grecaptcha.render(recaptchas[i].id, {
            sitekey: '__SITE_KEY___',
            callback: function (response) {
                if (response) {
                    var requestType = $(_form).data('type');
                    switch (requestType) {
                        case 'ajax':
                            var deferred = new $.Deferred();
                            pajax({
                                url: $(_form).attr('action'),
                                type: 'POST',
                                data: $(_form).serialize(),
                                cache: false
                            }).then(function f(data) {
                                    responseTemplate(
                                        _form,
                                        '.form-request-body',
                                        'Headline',
                                        'Text...'
                                    );

                                    grecaptcha.reset(recaptchaObj[i]);
                                    deferred.resolve(data);
                                }
                            ).catch(function f(error) {
                                console.error(error);
                            });
                            break;
                        case 'default':
                            _form.submit();
                            grecaptcha.reset(recaptchaObj[i]);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }, true);
    }
}
```

EDIT: Forms looks like this

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" data-type="ajax" class="modal__validator custom-width no-scroll" action="/contact">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST" />

    <!-- some more input fields here -->

    <div id="recap_ring_custom_width" class="g-recaptcha" data-size="invisible"></div>
    <input type="submit" class="action-link active" value="Absenden"/>
</form>

<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" data-type="ajax" class="modal__validator custom-strength no-scroll" action="/contact">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST" />

    <!-- some more input fields here -->

    <div id="recap_ring_custom_width" class="g-recaptcha" data-size="invisible"></div>
    <input type="submit" class="action-link active" value="Absenden"/>
</form>

<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" data-type="default" class="modal__validator contact no-scroll" action="/contact">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST" />

    <!-- some more input fields here -->

    <div id="recap_ring_custom_width" class="g-recaptcha" data-size="invisible"></div>
    <input type="submit" class="action-link active" value="Absenden"/>
</form>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: "several forms" on a page?  You need to closely examine your code structure.  Sounds like a problem with trying to get multiple forms to share one captcha code.  I don't think that's possible.  You may want to refer to the Google reCaptcha documentation and examples.

Comment: Also, *"forms look like this"* is not showing what we'd need to see.  They do not look like `<?= $this->Form->create ... `  <- that is un-rendered server-side PHP code from some un-named PHP framework.  Your JavaScript never sees your PHP so it's irrelevant to troubleshooting client-side code.  Only show us the relevant rendered HTML output as it appears in the browser DOM.

Comment: Took me a few seconds to find this same question, complete with jQuery Validate too:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/43872550/594235

Comment: @Sparky, thanks for the hint. This solved my Problem ```grecaptcha.execute(recaptchaObj[index])```